# JS dependency priority

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I have 3 files in a dir like this:

```
models
     |_ Service.js
     |_ Agent.js
     |_ index.js
```

**Index.js**

```
export * from Service;
export * from Agent;
```

**Agent.js**

```
class Agent {

  id = 0
}
export {Agent}
```

**Service.js**

```
import {Agent} from '.'

class Service {
   agent = new Agent();
}

export {Service}
```

But when I wanna make an instance of `Service` the `Agent` type is undefined, while if I change the priority of exports in `index.js` the problem would be solved.

**index.js (After change the priority)**

```
export * from Agent;
export * from Service;
```

Would someone please tell where did I make mistake?

Answer (score 3):

The code above contains circular dependency which isn't needed here.

Imports are supposed to explicitly state that one module depends on another one.

It should be:

```
import {Agent} from './Agent'

class Service {
   agent = new Agent();
}

export {Service}
```

In this case the order in which they are imported in index.js doesn't matter.